# React state always returning previous (or initial) state inside callback from fabricjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fabricjs

The code below is my minimal issue reproduce component. It initializes fabric canvas, and handles "mode" state. Mode state determines whether canvas can be edited and a simple button controls that state.

The problem is that even if `mode,setMode` works correctly (meaning - components profiler shows correct state after button click, also text inside button shows correct state), the state returned from `mode` hook inside fabric event callback, still returns initial state.

I suppose that the problem is because of the function passed as callback to fabric event. It seems like the callback is "cached" somehow, so that inside that callback, all the states have initial values, or values that were in state before passing that callback.

How to make this work properly? I would like to have access to proper, current state inside fabric callback.

```
const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState<fabric.Canvas | null>(null);
const [mode, setMode] = useState("freerun");
const canvasRef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
const modes = ["freerun", "edit"];

React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
      height: 800,
      width: 800,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    });

    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (this: typeof canvas, opt: fabric.IEvent) {
      const evt = opt.e as any;
      console.log("currentMode", mode) // Not UPDATING - even though components profiler shows that "mode" state is now "edit", it still returns initial state - "freerun".
      if (mode === "edit") {
         console.log("edit mode, allow to scroll, etc...");
      }
    });

    setCanvas(canvas);
    return () => canvas.dispose();
}, [canvasRef])

const setNextMode = () => {
  const index = modes.findIndex(elem => elem === mode);
  const nextIndex = index + 1;
  if (nextIndex >= modes.length) {
    setMode(modes[0])
  } else {
    setMode(modes[nextIndex]);
  }
}

return (
<>
  <div>
    <button onClick={setNextMode}>Current mode: { mode }</button>
  </div>
  {`Current width: ${width}`}
  <div id="fabric-canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
  </div>
</>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `mode` is read and it's value saved inside the callback during the callback's creation and, from there, never update again.

In order to solve this you have to add `mode` on the `useEffect` dependencies. In this way each time that `mode` changes React will run again the `useEffect` and the callback will receive the updated (and correct) value.

Comment: Thanks alot! Works now. I updated the answer with correct code. 
Also question - could the same problem be solved using `useCallback` hook?

Comment: It depedens on how you write the code. If you put the callback inside a `useCallback` and then add it to the `useEffect` dependencies then yes, it should works.

Comment: Thanks! What is worth saying, fabric doesn't replace callbacks on next run. It stores them, so that after another useEffect call, there will be two callbacks for the same event. The solution is to clear the events at the bottom of useEffect, something like `return () => { canvas.off("eventName") }`

Answer (score 1):

That's true! It worked now, thanks Marco.

Now to **not** run `setCanvas` on each mode change, I ended up creating another `useEffect` hook to hold attaching canvas events **only**. The final code looks similar to this:

```
const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState<fabric.Canvas | null>(null);
const [mode, setMode] = useState("freerun");
const canvasRef = React.useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
const modes = ["freerun", "edit"];

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvas) {
      return;
    }

    // hook for attaching canvas events
    fabric.Image.fromURL(gd, (img) => {
      if (canvas) {
        canvas.add(img)
        disableImageEdition(img);
      }
    });


    canvas.on('mouse:down', function (this: typeof canvas, opt: fabric.IEvent) {
      const evt = opt.e as any;
      console.log("currentMode", mode) // works correctly now
      if (mode === "edit") {
         console.log("edit mode, allow to scroll, etc...");
      }
    });

  }, [canvas, mode])

React.useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasRef.current, {
      height: 800,
      width: 800,
      backgroundColor: 'yellow'
    });

    setCanvas(canvas);
    return () => canvas.dispose();
}, [canvasRef])

const setNextMode = () => {
  const index = modes.findIndex(elem => elem === mode);
  const nextIndex = index + 1;
  if (nextIndex >= modes.length) {
    setMode(modes[0])
  } else {
    setMode(modes[nextIndex]);
  }
}

return (
<>
  <div>
    <button onClick={setNextMode}>Current mode: { mode }</button>
  </div>
  {`Current width: ${width}`}
  <div id="fabric-canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas ref={canvasRef} />
  </div>
</>
)
```

I also wonder if there are more ways to solve that - is it possible to solve this using `useCallback` hook?