# Getting initial useState list values when returning from a sub componet to save data instead of current state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-bootstrap, use-state

I have recreated my problem in a simplified code example.
Follow these steps to reproduce it:

1. Click on one of the *three list items* to edit the value in the off-canvas box.
2. Change the value and click the save button.
3. Select a different item to edit & save.
4. Note: the original edited item has reverted back to its initial state.
   I have the console.logging in the save method to show that the list(state) is not the current (visible) version but the initial state.

[Sandbox code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-colden-2wvks?file=/src/App.js)

I have an inelegant solution(workaround) that I will put as an answer but it doesn't explain what or why this is happening.  I have 3 off-canvas editors like this on my page & one does work as expected but the other two loose state when calling their save functions in the parent.

Comment: not sure how to get the sandbox code to embed properly... please provide a link to directions or suggest an edit if you know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I found the answer that I was looking for.
Thanks to [Marco Nisi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3938386/marco-nisi) for [this Answer to a very similar question that has not got much attention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68496636/4019273)

My forked code solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-napier-mn1r0?file=/src/App.js)

The solution is to move the callback (save function) into be created when the canvas is shown instead of when the functional component is initialized creating a fresher clone of the state.  I can still see this as being problematic if you have an example where the state is being updated in the background or if the off-canvas is not blocking other edits.  **Note: You don't need the callback defined in the open function but it does need to be added(replaced) to the props object there.**

```
  function open(e, item, itemIndex) {
    save = (edit, index) => {
      console.log(myList);
      const newList = [...myList];
      newList[index] = edit;
      setMyList(newList);
      setPropArgs({ ...propArgs, show: false });
    };
    setPropArgs({
      ...propArgs,
      editThis: item,
      index: itemIndex,
      show: true,
      save: save
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my bad (ugly) workaround:

1. Pass the state object (myList) to the child in props object.

App.js

```
  function open(e, item, itemIndex) {
    setPropArgs({ ...propArgs, editThis: item, index: itemIndex, show: true, itemList: myList });
  }
```

2. Return the list back to the parent in save method call & use the passed variable instead of state.

MyEditor.js

```
    <Button type="button" onClick={(e) => props.save(edit, props.index, props.itemList)}>
      Save
    </Button>
```

App.js

```
  function save(edit, index, itemList) {
    // console.log(myList);
    const newList = [...itemList];
    newList[index] = edit;
    setMyList(newList);
    setPropArgs({ ...propArgs, show: false });
  }
```

This is bad because MyEditor shouldn't need to know anything about the parent, it doesn't read or edit the list at all & there shouldn't be a need to pass around a copy of the state that could become out of date (if I wasn't blocking with the canvas).